# Why is it taking so long to open a connection to my database?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, adodb

I've created some code to pull information from an sql database into excel via a custom function. At the moment, the code takes about 5-7 seconds just to open the connection. All other parts of the code, including the query itself is very quick. Any idea why it'd be taking so long?

This is for a sqlsever that I have on my local machine.

```
Function Lob_amt(sp_name As String, l_date As String) As Double


Dim Conn As ADODB.Connection
Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection
Dim recset As ADODB.Recordset
Set recset = New ADODB.Recordset

Dim l_year As Double
Dim l_name As String


l_year = Year(l_date)



Dim sqlQry As String, sConnect As String

sqlQry = "SELECT sum(lob_lobbying.Amount)FROM lob_lobbying" & _
    " WHERE lob_lobbying.Latest = 'Y'" & _
    " AND lob_lobbying.IndTot ='Y'" & _
    " AND UltOrg = '" & sp_name & "'" & _
    " AND CycleYear in ('" & l_year & "')"

sConnect = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=DESKTOP-L9CVIVP;Database=lobbying;Trusted_Connection=yes;"


Conn.Open sConnect

recset.Open sqlQry, Conn

If IsNull(recset.Fields(0).Value) Then
    Lob_amt = 0
    Else

    Lob_amt = recset.Fields(0).Value

    End If
recset.Close
Conn.Close
Set recset = Nothing
Set Conn = Nothing


End Function
```

I expected the connection to take ms, but it's taking 5-7 seconds to open the connection. With my current setup as a custom function, Ill be pulling in the neighborhood of 80,000 queries. I could change the setup somewhat so that I'm not using the custom function anymore, but the connection time seems unusually long.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: If you manually open the Database, is it quicker than 5-7 seconds ?

Comment: Yes, less than one second using SSMS.

Comment: Okay .. to be sure that the connection is taking that long, can you go through your code using F8 Step by Step ?

Comment: Vague thought.  You say the Database opens quickly when you open it manually.  But how are you doing this?  I'm thinking it might not be the time to _open_ the database but the time to _start_ SQL?  It's been a while since I had SQL running locally but it would be worth checking.

Comment: I was opening it in SSMS, which I have running in the background while excel is open, so sql is running. Thanks for the tips though!

Answer (score 0):

Try to profile your code by executing this and study immediate window (opened by `Ctrl` + `G` in VBA editor:

```vb
    Function Lob_amt(sp_name As String, l_date As String) As Double

    Debug.Print "begin Lob_amt function: " & Strings.Format(Now, "HH:nn:ss") & "." & Strings.Right(Strings.Format(Timer, "#0.00"), 2)
    Dim Conn As ADODB.Connection
    Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Dim recset As ADODB.Recordset
    Set recset = New ADODB.Recordset

    Dim l_year As Double
    Dim l_name As String


    l_year = Year(l_date)



    Dim sqlQry As String, sConnect As String

    sqlQry = "SELECT sum(lob_lobbying.Amount)FROM lob_lobbying" & _
        " WHERE lob_lobbying.Latest = 'Y'" & _
        " AND lob_lobbying.IndTot ='Y'" & _
        " AND UltOrg = '" & sp_name & "'" & _
        " AND CycleYear in ('" & l_year & "')"
    Debug.Print vbNewLine & sqlQry & vbNewLine
    sConnect = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=DESKTOP-L9CVIVP;Database=lobbying;Trusted_Connection=yes;"


    Conn.Open sConnect
        Debug.Print "Lob_amt function Conn.Open: " & Strings.Format(Now, "HH:nn:ss") & "." & Strings.Right(Strings.Format(Timer, "#0.00"), 2)
    recset.Open sqlQry, Conn

    If IsNull(recset.Fields(0).Value) Then
        Lob_amt = 0
           Debug.Print "Lob_amt Lob_amt = 0: " & Strings.Format(Now, "HH:nn:ss") & "." & Strings.Right(Strings.Format(Timer, "#0.00"), 2)
        Else

        Lob_amt = recset.Fields(0).Value
                    Debug.Print "Lob_amt recset.Fields(0).Valu: " & Strings.Format(Now, "HH:nn:ss") & "." & Strings.Right(Strings.Format(Timer, "#0.00"), 2)
        End If

    recset.Close
    Debug.Print "Lob_amt recset closed: " & Strings.Format(Now, "HH:nn:ss") & "." & Strings.Right(Strings.Format(Timer, "#0.00"), 2)
    Conn.Close
    Debug.Print "Lob_amt conn closed: " & Strings.Format(Now, "HH:nn:ss") & "." & Strings.Right(Strings.Format(Timer, "#0.00"), 2)
    Set recset = Nothing
    Set Conn = Nothing


    End Function
```

Problem maybe in other functions as modules

UPD: 
`SELECT sum(lob_lobbying.Amount)FROM lob_lobbying WHERE lob_lobbying.Latest = 'Y' AND lob_lobbying.IndTot ='Y' AND UltOrg = 'Cigna Corp' AND CycleYear in ('2006')`
this generated query is passed to `Open` method, so these freezes (up to 5 sec) not due to `Open` method itself, but due to executing this query, that contains conditions and group operations (`SUM`) on SQL Server, so this is problem of database. This issue, if it very uncomfortable, should be solved by other approaches (indexing, data dividing, OLAP and so on)

Comment: I'm getting the following: 

begin Lob_amt function: 06:01:47.45
Lob_amt function Conn.Open: 06:01:52.99
Lob_amt recset.Fields(0).Valu: 06:01:53.39
Lob_amt recset closed: 06:01:53.39

So, the problem does appear to be sitting at the Conn.open line.

Comment: And it is due to using sum function I think. Try to run your query with `sum()` values in SSMS, and it will get same time costs for executing, I think. Edited answer for debug output the SQL string to be checked in SSMS

Comment: The summation should be done within SSMS, the query should only be outputting a single value. I'm getting this output: begin Lob_amt function: 06:18:10.86

SELECT sum(lob_lobbying.Amount)FROM lob_lobbying WHERE lob_lobbying.Latest = 'Y' AND lob_lobbying.IndTot ='Y' AND UltOrg = 'Cigna Corp' AND CycleYear in ('2006')

Lob_amt function Conn.Open: 06:18:15.94
Lob_amt recset.Fields(0).Valu: 06:18:16.35
Lob_amt recset closed: 06:18:16.35
Lob_amt conn closed: 06:18:16.35

Comment: Try to run generated query `SELECT sum(lob_lobbying.Amount)FROM lob_lobbying WHERE lob_lobbying.Latest = 'Y' AND lob_lobbying.IndTot ='Y' AND UltOrg = 'Cigna Corp' AND CycleYear in ('2006')` in SSMS, you should get same 5 sec, I think

Comment: I'd bet that open is launching several second, because it launches this generated query, that contains conditions and sum operations. So problem about time is to speed-up the *database performance*, if it possible. Applying indexes, or other approaches, even OLAP, I think. But maybe it is just circumstances to be patient about it.